# Fastest way to determine best variables to get highest return

Tags: node.js, algorithm, performance

I'm trying to find the best variables for a stock trading bot in order to get the best return. Even with a small amount of data, its already doing multiple hundred billion loops which takes a while. When I scale this up with more data, it will take even longer to find the best variables.

What I'm doing is having multiple nested loops that try every different scenario to determine the best variables to get the highest return.

Below is an example. While it's obvious what the best variables for this scenario is, its just a mockup of what I'm doing and isn't code from the project, but rather just a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
let bestReturn = 0;
for (let variableOne = 0; variableOne < 10; variableOne++) {
  for (let variableTwo = 0; variableTwo < 10; variableTwo++) {
    for (let variableThree = 0; variableThree < 10; variableThree++) {
      if ((variableOne * variableTwo * variableThree) > bestReturn) {
        bestReturn = variableOne * variableTwo * variableThree
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm currently just running this on my Windows PC, but is there system that handles this process faster, like Linux for example? or is there a better way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: The innermost loop will iterate 1,000 times here; where does "multiple hundred billion loops" come from? And what specific problem are you trying to solve? You could delete these loops and just write `let bestReturn = 9 * 9 * 9;` since that's the maximum you can make by multiplying three of these numbers.

Comment: @kaya3 The code snippet is mearly a mockup example to show what I'm trying to do. My actual project has alot more nested loops as it has to figure out alot more variables and with alot more data is comes out to billions of loops. Because of the nature of it, I can't show my code, but the snippet gets the point across. The variables or the manipulation of them to determine bestReturn can be anything, all I'm trying to do is find a faster way to loop through variables and find the "best return"

Comment: The snippet doesn't get your point across, because it could be replaced with just doing `9 * 9 * 9`. If the innermost loop body could do "anything" then there is nothing we can suggest; nobody can simplify "do X 100 billion times" without knowing what X is.

Comment: look into `SlidingWindow`

Comment: you may show your real goal function.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a grid search (that is essential that your loops are doing) on a hyperdimensional parameter space does not seem to be very promising. But at least you can increase the size of your grid and refine your search after the first rough scanning of the parameter space.

Parameter optimization is a huge field and at least for generic goal functions that can not be solved analytically the best you can do is to apply heuristics to find some (and hopefully a quite good one) local minimum.

The downhill simplex method is extremely easy to implement and quite efficient. so maybe you want to start with this. 
Consider to run it multiple times with randomized starting parameters.